# Code only texting me one article rather then all of my scraped data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, twilio

I am trying to scrape data (text) off a website and send it to my phone as an SMS using Twilio. I am using selenium to scrape 5 'articles' from my favourite game and then appending a list which I then send as an SMS to my iphone. I use a for loop to get each article and then add it to the list.

```
lst = []
news = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("article")
for new in news[:5]:
    the_big_news= str(new.text)
    print(the_big_news)
    print(divider)
    lst.append(new.text + divider)
   

print(lst)


account_sid = '[sid]'
auth_token = '[token]'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
    messaging_service_sid='[mssid]',
    body = lst,
    to='[my number]'
)

print(message.sid)
```

When I run this, I get a text but it is only the first article followed by the divider rather than all the 5 like how it prints out on pycharm. It seems as if my for loop is only running once but i know thats not true because it prints all five articles. My question is how can I get this code to send me all five articles rather then just the first one. If you need me to send more code, i can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could use body = '\n'.join(lst) to get it as one message

Comment: @Red oh that works. I just tested it. Thanks a ton. Although now I have the issue of the character limit but thats not a worry.